# Pinescript preventing duplicate signals

Tags: pine-script

I am writing an indicator in Pinescript to give me long and short signals.  How do I prevent it from giving me the same signal twice?  In other words, if I am already long, I don't want another long signal.

I am using the long_cond function.  Essentially, I want the code to operate like this:

long_cond = condition1 and condition2 and "don't enter if already long"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383816/risk-management-if-already-long-then-do-not-place-new-order/58387805#58387805

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you Baris!