# Display text only the first time

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to display buy 1 time only if the condition met instead of repeatedly display the condition multiple times in the next couple bars.

```
Buy = rising(cci(close,200),12) and ccinum>=100
Plotchar(buy,location=location.abovebar,color=color.green,text=“buy”)
```

This code will display buy multiple time consecutively.  I want it to display 1 time until sell condition is met then reset.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383816/risk-management-if-already-long-then-do-not-place-new-order/58387805#58387805

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I needed.